# netatalk 'vol size limit' causes Time Machine to report 0 KB available

Tags: file-sharing, apple

When I set the `vol size limit` in `/etc/netatalk/afp.conf`, Time Machine initially reports the correct amount of available, but fails on backup and reports that 0 KB are available. I am wondering if this might be because I have a share pointing to `/data` and another (Time Machine) share pointing to `/data/mbp_time_machine`. The [netatalk docs](https://netatalk.sourceforge.io/3.0/htmldocs/afp.conf.5.html) specify that "you MUST NOT use this volume to store other content when using this option", but I do not know if they are referring to the AFP volume or the actual logical volume on the host.

Below is my `afp.conf`:

```
;
; Netatalk 3.x configuration file
;

[Global]
; Global server settings
hostname=redacted_afp
[Homes]
basedir regex = /home

[redacted_afp]
path = /data

[carson Time Machine]
path = /data/mbp_time_machine
time machine = yes
vol size limit=1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but it needs an answer for someone stumbling here from Google. The size limit specified is in megabytes (MiB), 1000 is less than 1GB - it's so small that it's unusable. Try changing that to a higher number, like 100000 for ~100GB.